# Summing values of an object by first filtering other unique values of the same object

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have a list of an object lets call this object Order which has a quantity and price as fields.

for example as below:

Object `Order` (fields `quantity` and `price`) list contains the below values:

```
Quantity  Price

5         200
6         100
3         200
1         300
```

Now I want to use Java-8 to fetch this list filtered in below way:

```
Quantity  Price

8         200
6         100
1         300
```

Price being the unique value to filter from and summing any quantity that the price has, I want to form a new list based on this.

Please suggest how i can do this with java 8 lambda expression, thanks.

Comment: You should provide your attempt as well :)

Comment: my attempt is too embarassing to show here lol @Nikolas

Comment: It's **never** embarrassing! It helps us to provide a better answer, give you feedback and help you to fix your current solution. Go on and post it. :)

Comment: @Nikolas i have a follow up question, what if i have a 3rd string that i would like to use in the    .map(e -> new Order(e.getKey(), e.getValue())). So what i mean is that my Order object doesn't just accept 2 fields, now it has a 3rd field which is a string for example, how would i fetch that from Order and add that in the new? Thanks a lot so far.

Comment: @Nikolas Sorry, very new to this, i tried something liek this but it wasn't working: `List<Order> buyOrdersSummed  = buyOrders.stream().collect(
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                  Collectors.groupingBy(Order::new,Collectors.summingLong(Order::getQuantity)),
                        map -> map.entrySet().stream()
                                .map(e -> new Order(e.getValue(), Order::getUserId, e.getKey()))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())));

Comment: Ah, I got you now. Try this: `List<Order> buyOrdersSummed = orders.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getPrice), map -> map.entrySet().stream().map(e -> new Order(e.getKey(), e.getValue().get(0).getUserId(), e.getValue().stream().mapToInt(i -> i.getQuantity()).sum())).collect(Collectors.toList())));`. Grouping will happen using the same key, but instead of `summingInt` you let produce `List<Order>. Then in the `finisher` you use these orders to calculate an `userId` (I assume the first one) and the `quantity` as a sum and pass it all to a new object.

Comment: @Nikolas wow thank you. I have learned a lot today thanks to you :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following `Stream` does the trick:

```
List<Order> o  = orders.stream().collect(
    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getPrice,Collectors.summingInt(Order::getQuantity)),
        map -> map.entrySet().stream()
                             .map(e -> new Order(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Let's break this down:

1. The following code returns a `Map<Integer, Integer>` which contains price as a key (the unique value you want to base the summing on) and its summed quantities. The key method is [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) with `classifier` describing the key and the `downstream` defining a value, which would be a sum of quantities, hence [`Collectors.summingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) (depends on the `quantity` type):

   ```
   Map<Integer, Integer> map = orders.stream().collect(
       Collectors.groupingBy(                            // I want a Map<Integer, Integer>
           Order::getPrice,                              // price is the key
           Collectors.summingInt(Order::getQuantity))    // sum of quantities is the value
   ```
2. The desired structure is `List<Order>`, therefore you want to use the [`Collectors.collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) method with a `Collector<T, A, R> downstream` and `Function<R, RR> finisher`. The `downstream` is the grouping from the first point, the finisher will be a conversion of `Map<Integer, Integer>` back to `List<Order>`:

   ```
   List<Order> o  = orders.stream().collect(
   Collectors.collectingAndThen(
       grouping,                                                 // you know this one ;)
       map -> map.entrySet()                        
                 .stream()                                       // iterate entries
                 .map(e -> new Order(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))  // new Order(qty, price)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList())));                // as a List<Order>
   ```